# Call async JavaScript function in WKWebView from Swift

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am trying to call a JavaScript function inside the page of a WKWebView from Swift using callAsyncJavaScript, however it claims the function does not exist.

Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: undefined is not a function, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}

Swift side:

```swift
let userScriptSource = try! String(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "main", ofType: "js")!)
let userScript = WKUserScript(source: userScriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        
conf.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: conf)
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url.deletingLastPathComponent())
```

Later, many seconds after page load, in response to a button press:

```swift
try! await webView.callAsyncJavaScript("return test();", in: nil, contentWorld: .defaultClient) as! String
```

JavaScript side:

```js
async function test() {
  // do async work
  return "hello world"
}
```

I have tried using both the .page and .defaultClient content worlds, the same problem exists in either. If I attach the safari console to the simulator and call the function it works fine.
I have tried both including the JS as a user script or having it load from a script tag in the html, neither works with any of the content world options.